# Asmack connected with server but lossing messages (Android)

Tags: android, chat, ejabberd, smack, asmack

i'm developing a chat using asmack in Android for the client and Ejabberd for the server. When the app is inactive for 10 minutes sometimes doesn't receive messages... then i go to the ejabberd server and i can see both users online. The Android user is online and it's not receiving messages.

I have added connections listeners to detect when user go offline, i have also added pingFailedListener, and a BroadcastReceiver to handle network change and reconnect...

Is anyone facing the same situation?

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to add a refresh mechanism for your app.

Comment: Did you checked jabber console if there is a configuration that stop pinging client if they away for specific ? time

Comment: please attach some code  in order to understand what is really going wrong!!!